# SQL - aggregate function - GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
select vkbr.vkID, vkbr.bid, vkbr.Date, vkbr.agID 
FROM camp c (NOLOCK)
JOIN ag (NOLOCK) ON ag.campID = c.id
JOIN vkbr WITH (NOLOCK) ON vkbr.agID = ag.id
where c.id = 648322
order by vkbr.vkID;
```

Which has the following results:

```
vkID        bid     Date                    agID
1072845175  NULL    2012-12-04 20:20:12.390 16074852
1072845177  0.74    2012-12-01 23:36:11.280 16074852
1072845177  0.18    2012-12-02 23:01:26.123 16074852
1072845177  0.72    2012-12-09 23:38:52.503 16074852
1072845177  0.62    2012-12-14 15:26:49.643 16074852
1072845178  2.91    2012-12-08 19:37:00.877 16074852
1072845178  0.73    2012-12-13 17:54:11.240 16074852
1072845178  2.70    2012-12-14 15:26:49.643 16074852
```

I need to group by vkID, get the max(Date) and the bid on the max(Date) to get this result:

```
1072845175  NULL    2012-12-04 20:20:12.390 16074852
1072845177  0.62    2012-12-14 15:26:49.643 16074852
1072845178  2.70    2012-12-14 15:26:49.643 16074852


select vkbr.vkID, MAX(vkbr.Date) as Date, MIN(vkbr.agID) as agID
FROM camp c (NOLOCK)
JOIN    ag (NOLOCK) ON ag.campID = c.id
JOIN    vkbr WITH (NOLOCK) ON vkbr.agID = ag.id
where c.id=648322
group by vkbr.vkID
having Max(vkbr.Date) is not null
and Max(Date) <= '2012-12-18';
```

Since I cannot add the bid column in SELECT statement - receive this error:
Column 'bid' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

So I tried to do this with temp tables:

```
create table #getBids ( 
vkID bigint not null,
Date datetime null,
agID bigint null);

insert into #getBids (vkID, Date, agID) 
select vkbr.vkID, MAX(vkbr.Date) as Date, MIN(vkbr.agID) as agID
FROM camp c (NOLOCK)
JOIN    ag (NOLOCK) ON ag.campID = c.id
JOIN    vkbr WITH (NOLOCK) ON vkbr.agID = ag.id
where c.id = 648322
group by vkbr.vkID
having Max(vkbr.Date) is not null
and Max(Date) <= '2012-12-18';

Now this gives me the result I want:

select vkbr.vkID, vkbr.bid from vkbr
inner join #getBids on vkbr.Date = #getBids.Date
and vkbr.agID = #getBids.agID
and vkbr.vkID = #getBids.vkID
```

I was wondering is there anyway to accomplish the same result in one query w/o creating the temp table? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you create your table schema in [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/) or show us the tables schema here please?

Comment: Politely recommend being more verbose in your naming schema, if possible.

Comment: Also, I don't think it's possible that you got that error on that query.  You're not pulling the "bid" column anywhere in that specific query.

Comment: +1 @blueSky for the presentation of the question and showing what you have tried :)

Comment: @bobCodigo: I've showed the schema in CREATE TABLE if that what you are asking for.

Comment: @NickVaccaro: I did not mention the query with bid here. If I try to get the bid, I receive the error I mentioned.

Comment: Yeah, you'll probably want to post the exact query that's giving you that error, assuming that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: @NickVaccaro: You are right. Sure for future posts.

Comment: Be advised that `NOLOCK` is deprecated in SQL Server 2012.  You may wish to refactor the query in light of that.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server 2005 or higher you can use the [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) function to select the row with `MAX(Date)` for each `vkID`.

I haven't been able to test this with your schema but I think it would work something like this:

First, declare a Common Table Expression (CTE) to add a row number to your query results

```
with cte as
(    
    select vkbr.vkID, vkbr.bid, vkbr.Date, vkbr.agID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY vkbr.vkID ORDER BY vkbr.Date DESC) AS RowNumber
    FROM camp c (NOLOCK)
    JOIN ag (NOLOCK) ON ag.campID = c.id
    JOIN vkbr WITH (NOLOCK) ON vkbr.agID = ag.id
    where c.id = 648322
)
```

Then, `SELECT` only where `RowNumber = 1`. This will give you the latest record for each `vkbr.vkID`

```
select vkID, bid, Date, agID
from cte
where RowNumber = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Query:

```
SELECT vkbr.vkID,
       vkbr.bid,
       vkbr.Date,
       vkbr.agID
FROM camp c (NOLOCK)
JOIN ag (NOLOCK) ON ag.campID = c.id
JOIN vkbr WITH (NOLOCK) ON vkbr.agID = ag.id
WHERE c.id = 648322
AND vkbr.Date = (SELECT MAX(v.Date)
                 FROM vkbr v2
                 WHERE v2.vkID = vkbr.vkID
                 AND v2.agID = vkbr.agID)
ORDER BY vkbr.vkID
```

Example Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5a18f/2)**

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE t1.Date = (SELECT MAX(t2.Date)
                 FROM Table1 t2
                 WHERE t1.vkID = t2.vkID
                 AND t1.agID = t2.agID)
```

Result:

```
|       VKID |    BID |                            DATE |     AGID |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1072845178 |   2.70 | December, 14 2012 15:26:49+0000 | 16074852 |
| 1072845177 |   0.62 | December, 14 2012 15:26:49+0000 | 16074852 |
| 1072845175 | (null) | December, 04 2012 20:20:12+0000 | 16074852 |
```

Comment: Thanks. Learned from it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with one query.  First, the query must gather the max date by vkID.  Next, it must join back to vkbr using the date to get the actual bid.  You could use a [sub-query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx), i.e. something lIke this:

```
select vkID, bid, Date, agID
from
(
    select vkbr.vkID, MAX(vkbr.Date) as Date, MIN(vkbr.agID) as agID
    from camp c with (nolock)
    inner join ag with (nolock)
        on ag.campID = c.id
    inner join vkbr with (nolock)
        on vkbr.agID = ag.id
    where c.id = 648322
    group by vkbr.vkID
    having Max(vkbr.Date) is not null
    and Max(vkbr.Date) <= '2012-12-18';
) MaxDate
    inner join vkbr with (nolock)
        on vkbr.agID = MaxDate.agID
        and vkbr.Date = MaxDate.Date
```

I would recommend using a [common table expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) (CTE) instead of a sub-query.  The CTE approach would look something like this:

```
;with MaxDate (vkID, Date, agID) as
(
    select vkbr.vkID, MAX(vkbr.Date) as Date, MIN(vkbr.agID) as agID
    from ...
)
select ...
from MaxDate
inner join vkbr
    on vkbr.agID = MaxDate.agID
    and vkbr.Date = MaxDate.Date
```

Comment: Although I've accepted a response already, but I try to learn from other responses. Would you please give me a complete query for your first approach, I cannot figure out what you are trying to do. Also the one with CTE if possible - I don't see where CTE have been used or mentioned.

Comment: The sub-query approach can be thought of like this: 1) Get the max date grouped however you want, then 2) join back to the table on that date to get the actual bid.  The CTE is the `with` statement in my and Tim S's answers.