# Simple query in sql through aggregate function and group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like the picture bellow and I need to extract the id,name and date of the max datetime that has been grouped by the name.

[image]

I can get the max datetime through this query:

```
SELECT MAX(Table.Date),Table.name FROM Table GROUP BY Table.name
```

and the result is:

[image]

To extract the information of max datetime that has been grouped by the name, I've had this query:

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.Date, t1.id
FROM Table t1
WHERE t1.Date in (SELECT MAX(t2.Date)
FROM Table t2
GROUP BY t2.name)
```

the result is:

[image]

but do not need the highlighted data. because between 'D's the 2014-01-12 has the max date.

**NOTE:** I can solve the problem through JOIN expression.

but because of **saving time** I need a simple query.

Comment: Did you see this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960671/sql-aggregate-function-group-by-clause?rq=1

Comment: @Leptonator yes I've seen that post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use row-number, partition by

```
Select * from
(Select *,rn=row_number()over(partition by name order by date desc) from table) x
Where x.rn = 1;
```

Comment: It does work! You need to define some indexes ... To obtain minimal performance ..