# Group only top n rows in sql

Tags: mysql

I have a table (myTab), which has 3 columns(id, marketValue, stock).

I want to group top n rows ordered by marketValue. I can think of this nested query.

```
SELECT AVG(marketValue), stock FROM (SELECT marketValue, stock FROM myTab
order by(marketValue) desc LIMIT(n)) GROUP BY stock.
```

Can we optimise it further? This is *not* to get top n rows of *each* group.

SAMPLE TABLE

[image]

If I group top 3 rows, the expected result should be :

[image]

Comment: Please read [Get top n records for each group of grouped results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't want for *each* group but group only top n rows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get top n records for each group of grouped results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results)

Comment: @Itisha share some sample records and expected resultset.

Comment: @James shared for your reference.

Comment: [Stack Overflow Discourages screenshots of code, errors & data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).  It is likely, the question will be downvoted, for containing unnecessary screenshots.  By using screenshots, you are discouraging anyone from assisting you.  No one wants to retype your stuff, from a screenshot, and screenshots are often, not readable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - aggregate function - GROUP BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960671/sql-aggregate-function-group-by-clause)

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY` clause your query is meaningless as the rows it returns are indeterminate.

Comment: @Itisha I hope you have the best one. As Nick suggested you can use `order by` clause or try including `pk` inside the sub query ti avoid indeterminate rows.

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represents unordered sets. So when we talked about first or last rows, We need to be deterministic with order of rows. Hence you need an order by clause in your inner query to get the top n rows. Rest looks fine -

```
SELECT AVG(marketValue), stock
FROM (SELECT marketValue, stock
      FROM myTab
      ORDER BY id
      LIMIT(n)
) X
GROUP BY stock
```

Comment: Can we avoid nested query ?

Comment: I guess no. Coz you should have top N records with you to get the average of them.